# couldnt understand implementaion of UpgradeabilityProxyFactory

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, openzeppelin-sdk, contract-upgrading

I want to use **UpgradeabilityProxy** provided by zeppelin, they have one method *createProxyAndCall* which they say initialize the new implementation with data parameter we provided which looks like:

```
   * @dev Creates an upgradeability proxy with initial implementation and calls it.
   * This is useful to initialize the proxied contract.
   * @param implementation Address of the initial implementation.
   * @param serviceRegistry service registry
   * @param data Data to send as msg.data in the low level call.
   * It should include the signature and the parameters of the function to be
   * called, as described in
   * https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#function-selector-and-argument-encoding.
   * @return Address of the new proxy.
   */


  function createProxyAndCall(
    address implementation,
    address serviceRegistry,
    bytes data
  ) public payable returns (MaintainableUpgradeabilityProxy) {
    MaintainableUpgradeabilityProxy proxy = _createProxy(implementation, serviceRegistry);
    // proxy.changeAdmin(owner);
    /* solium-disable-next-line */
    require(address(proxy).call.value(msg.value)(data), "failed to call proxy with data");

    if (autoActivate) {
      Activatable(address(proxy)).activate();
    }

    return proxy;
  }
```

*1) I am confused with how it is initializing the data, can someone please help me understand what this line is doing?*

```
require(address(proxy).call.value(msg.value)(data), "failed to call proxy with data");
```

reference link: [openzep](https://docs.zeppelinos.org/docs/1.4.0/upgradeability_upgradeabilityproxyfactory#createProxyAndCall)

*2) Also can you please tell me how to pass data to the given function, if my logic contract needs 3 parameters of String, uint and address type how shall I pass that in function createProxyAndCall()?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to initialize your contract is to use the interactive commands when creating the contract using `openzeppelin create`.

You will be asked `? Do you want to call a function on the instance after creating it?`, choose `Yes`, then the initialize function and you will be asked to provide the value for each parameter in turn.

A simple example contract and deploying is shown below:

### Counter.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/Initializable.sol";

contract Counter is Initializable {
    uint256 public value;

    function initialize(uint256 initialValue) initializer public {
        value = initialValue;
    }

    function increase() public {
        value++;
    }
}
```

### openzeppelin create

Deploy contract, select yes to call the initialize function after creating the contract and then provide the parameters.

```
$ npx openzeppelin create
✓ Compiled contracts with solc 0.5.11 (commit.c082d0b4)
? Pick a contract to instantiate Counter
? Pick a network development
✓ Added contract Counter
✓ Contract Counter deployed
All contracts have been deployed
? Do you want to call a function on the instance after creating it? Yes
? Select which function * initialize(initialValue: uint256)
? initialValue (uint256): 42
✓ Setting everything up to create contract instances
✓ Instance created at 0x25D02115bd67258a406A0F676147E6C3598a91a9
0x25D02115bd67258a406A0F676147E6C3598a91a9
```

---

The recommended way to use the OpenZeppelin SDK is via the command line interface, if a programmatic interface is preferred then please see the documentation:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/sdk/2.5/zos-lib

As an example, using the same Counter.sol contract, if using with Truffle, first compile.

```
$ npx truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Counter.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/Initializable.sol
> Artifacts written to /mnt/c/Users/andre/Documents/projects/forum/upgrade/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang
```

### index.js

Create a script to deploy the Counter contract and initialize

The parameters are passed to the initialize function using: `{ initArgs: [42] }`

```
// Required by @openzeppelin/upgrades when running from truffle
global.artifacts = artifacts;
global.web3 = web3;

// Import dependencies from OpenZeppelin SDK programmatic library
const { Contracts, SimpleProject, ZWeb3 } = require('@openzeppelin/upgrades')

async function main() {

  /* Initialize OpenZeppelin's Web3 provider. */
  ZWeb3.initialize(web3.currentProvider)

  /* Retrieve compiled contract artifacts. */
  const Counter = Contracts.getFromLocal('Counter');

  /* Retrieve a couple of addresses to interact with the contracts. */
  const [creatorAddress, initializerAddress] = await ZWeb3.accounts();

  /* Create a SimpleProject to interact with OpenZeppelin programmatically. */
  const myProject = new SimpleProject('MyProject', null, { from: creatorAddress });

  /* Deploy the contract with a proxy that allows upgrades. Initialize it by setting the value to 42. */
  const instance = await myProject.createProxy(Counter, { initArgs: [42] })
  console.log('Counter\'s value:', (await instance.methods.value().call({ from: initializerAddress })).toString());

}

// For truffle exec
module.exports = function(callback) {
  main().then(() => callback()).catch(err => callback(err))
};
```

### Deploy Counter contract and initialize

Execute the script

```
$ npx truffle exec index.js
Using network 'development'.

Counter's value: 42
```

---

Note: Your question gave a link to a much older version of the documentation, the latest is: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/sdk/2.5/

I assume you may be using an older version of OpenZeppelin SDK (pre version 2).  I recommend using the latest version of OpenZeppelin SDK.

The above used OpenZeppelin SDK 2.5.2

```
$ npx openzeppelin --version
2.5.2
```

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin